# How to use Azure ADB2C signup flow with custom subscription plans options?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, razorpay

I have a scenario and for what I believe is a common scenario for many websites :)

I have a website that uses Nextjs for frontend and asp.net core as backend. It uses Azure ADB2C for managing its users.

Now When the user is registering, I will collect some basic details which would be done through the userflows in Azure ADB2C.

Before the user creation is completed, I want to come back to my website to allow the user to select the subscription option and let the user click on subscribe button.

Based on this, there will be a call to third party payment gateway service like stripe/RazorPay... which takes over and allows the user to complete payment.

The payment gateway would send the success/failure notification back to my website which I will use to decide to proceed to complete user creation or discard the creation process.

*Using ADB2C seems to be quite a big task with custom policies :)*

Need help/suggestions/links

**Is it possible for us to come back to my website from ADB2C in between the registering process? I see an option using Custom policies with REST call, but will that really help? This is not just a REST call**.

OR

**Is it possible for me to let the user first choose the subscription option and then pass on that data to the ADB2C userflow. Not sure if we can pass data that way to the signup userflow. if you have any link that does that please share it with me**.

The second option seems to be more easy if I have a way to send some input to the signup flow.

Answer (score 1):

With custom policies, it is possible to extend the signup screen by adding subscription options.

Then call a REST API to the payment gateway.

This will return to B2C.

If all is good, write the user data to B2C.

If not, display an error message and discard the data.